# CSS button hover/link only when you hover on the top of it

Tags: css

http://justxp.plutohost.net/gxx/

Try hovering the buttons.

The hover / link will only work if you hover on the head of the buttons.
Why is this happening?

This is the code:

```
    <a href="#">
        <div class="button-1">
            <span class="bebas">play</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="button-1">
            <span class="bebas">community</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <div class="button-1">
            <span class="bebas">account help</span>
        </div>
    </a>
```

css

```
   .button-1 {
   background-image: url("../img/buttonoff.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 302px;
height: 82px;
margin-left: 1.4%;
margin-top: 1%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
line-height: 90px;
-webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.button-1:hover {
background-image: url("../img/buttonon.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 302px;
height: 82px;
-webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
```

I see nothing wrong with that?
I tried making the height bigger, still doesn't work.

I'm very curious about this!

Comment: The news element that comes after is sitting on top of the buttons. You need to have that element clear the buttons try floating them left or something to give display: block; and apply some margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a margin on your class news:

```
.news {
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    margin-top: 65px;
}
```

Edit:

Bonus! Please use css3 background gradients instead of images on background of your buttons.

[gradients.glrzad.com](http://gradients.glrzad.com)

Hope this helps, sorry if I miss interfered.

Answer (score 0):

Your this div is overlayering the buttons

```
<div class="news">
```

what you can do is :

Either you add this:

```
<br clear="all"/> //<---add this just above the div class named "news"
```

or you can adjust your css for the div `class news`:

```
.news {
   position: relative;
   top: 24%;
 }
```